# Merge DataSources in Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

Hello i need to "merge" 2 DataTables in one datagridview and i can't handle it. So far i have sth like this code below and now i want to place another datatable(it have the same number of columns) just below this without any separation(just like adding new rows). For example the code below returns 3 rows so i want my data from another source to appear starting in row 4, how can i do this ? Anyone can help ?

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String name = "Items";
        String constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                        "C:\\test.xlsx" +
                        ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;';";

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
        OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [" + name + "$]", con);
        con.Open();

        OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
        DataTable data = new DataTable();

        sda.Fill(data);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
    }
```

Comment: The DataTable class has a [Merge method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge(v=vs.110).aspx).  If you are just adding rows, try adding them to the DataSource, which is `data` in your code.  Maybe move the declaration of `data` to the form scope.

Comment: DataTables also have an [ImportRow method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.importrow.aspx), too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Add a new DataTable for another datasource and then add new datarow to first datatable (data)
Then add the columns and relevant data to it.

Do all this after filling first datatable from db.

take reference from this

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/670856/how-to-add-new-row-and-new-values-in-gridview-in-a